# New column with the first value of an established range

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

How can I add a new column with the first value of each range previously calculated and repeated side by side of values (within range)?

This is the code that I used to create 'categories':

```
bins=[0, 0.04439, 0.08878, 0.13317, 0.17756, 0.22195, 0.26634, 0.31073, 
  0.35512, 0.39951, 0.4439, 0.48829, 0.53268, 0.57707, 0.62146, 0.66585, 
   0.71024, 0.75463, 0.79902]

  df3['categories'] = pd.cut(df3['Distance(m)'], bins)

  df8 = df3.groupby('categories')['Hauteur_Acum(cm)'].agg({'max': 'max', 
  'min': 'min', 'average': 'mean'})
```

and this is the code to create a DF of the first value by range:

```
  df81 = df3.groupby('categories')['Hauteur_Acum(cm)'].agg({'value': 
  'first'})
```

the df3 is:

```
                                        Hauteur_Acum(cm)        categories
 0       0.000000    35.760384  ...          0.000000               NaN
 1       0.002222   155.800401  ...          0.047999     (0.0, 0.0444]
 2       0.002963   372.240662  ...          0.538474     (0.0, 0.0444]
 3       0.005185   571.810684  ...          1.094536     (0.0, 0.0444]
 4       0.006666   758.715072  ...          1.243944     (0.0, 0.0444]
 5       0.008888   941.509872  ...          1.246167     (0.0, 0.0444]
 6       0.010369  1022.736674  ...          1.432927     (0.0, 0.0444]
 7       0.012591  1112.566566  ...          1.508076     (0.0, 0.0444]
 8       0.014813  1132.676551  ...          1.417364     (0.0, 0.0444]
 9       0.015554  1114.860993  ...          1.419143     (0.0, 0.0444]
```

I want to insert a new column called df3['First_values'] with the first value repeatedly inside of range next to the range column.

I've tried this code:

```
df3['First_value(cm)']= np.where(df3['categories'] == '(0.0, 0.0444]', df81.iat[0,0],'')
```

... but still doesn't work
This is what I want:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying a lot of ways to solve the problem and the follow code was the only that I found.

First values of each category

```
df81 = df3.groupby('categories')['Hauteur_Acum(cm)'].agg({'First_value(cm)': 'first'})
```

I've rename `df3['categories']` to `df3['n_cat']` because it was a categorical series and is more easy to me identified as 1,2,3,4.... until 18 category.

```
df3['n_cat'] = df3['categories']

df3['n_cat'] = df3['n_cat'].cat.rename_categories([1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18])
```

I added the column 'data' into the df81 data frame

```
 df81['data']= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

Then, I assign the df81.iat[0,0] value to the new df3['donnees'] column by identifying the number of category (1, 2... until 18).

I didn't like very much this part because the code is too long

```
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 1, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[0,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 2, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[1,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 3, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[2,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 4, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[3,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 5, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[4,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 6, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[5,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 7, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[6,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 8, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[7,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 9, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[8,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 10, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[9,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 11, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[10,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 12, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[11,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 13, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[12,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 14, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[13,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 15, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[14,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 16, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[15,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 17, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[16,0]
df3.loc[df3['n_cat'] == 18, 'donnees'] = df81.iat[17,0]
```

But still.... this code solve the problem.

May be someone can help me to reduce or simplify my code.